# i cant populate select in jquery,my code is in razor c#, i try this

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, razor

the content of the table is this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGZI8.jpg)

```
@section scripts{
        <script>
            function adddata() {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '?handler=GetItems',
                    headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                    data: { Id: $("#IdSelectIdPuesto").val() },
                    success: function (data) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        $("#IdSelectlocalidad").append("<option value='" + data[i].value +
                        "' selected>" + data[i].text + "</option>");
                        

                        }
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("fail");
                    }
                })
            }
        </script>
    }
```

```
public JsonResult OnPostGetItems(int Id)
        {
            //displaydata1 =  rTDBContext.Turnos.ToList();
            
            var displayda = (from c in displaydata1
                             select c.LocNombre).Distinct().ToList();
            
            return new JsonResult(new List<SelectListItem> = { new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "LOcalidad" + 1 }, new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "LOcalidad" + 2 } });
            
        }
```

i'm trying a select distinct and add to the specified select  the id and the locNombre to the text

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the options of `$("#IdSelectlocalidad")` with the id passed from ajax,here is a demo:

```
public JsonResult OnPostGetItems(int Id)
        {
            //displaydata1 =  rTDBContext.Turnos.ToList();
            var displayda = (from c in l
                             where c.Id==Id select new SelectListItem { Text=c.LocNombre, Value=c.Id+""}).Distinct().ToList();
           
            return new JsonResult(displayda);

        }
```

js(remove `selected` in the option,with the code it will select the first option by default):

```
@section scripts{
        <script>
            function adddata() {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '?handler=GetItems',
                    headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                    data: { Id: $("#IdSelectIdPuesto").val() },
                    success: function (data) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        $("#IdSelectlocalidad").append("<option value='" + data[i].value +
                        "' >" + data[i].text + "</option>");
                        

                        }
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("fail");
                    }
                })
            }
        </script>
    }
```

Comment: Thank Yiyi You onr more tiem, but the problrem now is that ie populating all record not distinct LocNombre, now bring me all data without any filter. can you helpme please...

Comment: i try this select new SelectListItem { Text = c.LocNombre.Distinct(), Value = c.Id + "" }).Distinc, but it not work.

Comment: Have you used `where` to filter data?

Comment: no Yiy i use this and the data came as spected but i could not use the SelectListItem to added

Comment: Excuse me i have used in sql

Comment: ar displayda = displaydata1.DistinctBy(x => x.LocNombre); but i could no use:select new SelectListItem { Text = c.LocNombre, Value = c.IdLocalidad + "" }).Distinct().ToList();

Comment: i'm newin  ajax and jquery i have tried to use select new SelectListItem { Text = c.LocNombre, Value = c.IdLocalidad + "" }).Distinct().ToList(); in the query

Comment: Can you use `var displayda = (from c in l
                             where c.Id==Id select new SelectListItem { Text=c.LocNombre, Value=c.Id+""}).Distinct().ToList();`?

Comment: i prove it, and this select all data and did not filter by .LocNombre

Comment: displaydata1 =  rTDBContext.Turnos.ToList();
   //var displayda = displaydata1.DistinctBy(x => x.LocNombre ).ToList();
   var displayda =
    (from c in displaydata1
     where c.Id == Id select new SelectListItem 
    { Text = c.LocNombre, Value = c.Id + "" })
    .Distinct().ToList();

Comment: what is spected is this

Comment: SELECT  distinct LocNombre from Turnos

Answer (score 0):

[thanks Yiyi You, ifound the correct answer i doit this way]

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWsIi.png  do as folow

```
displaydata1 =  rTDBContext.Turnos.ToList();
        var display = displaydata1.DistinctBy(x => x.LocNombre ).ToList();
        var displayda = (from c in display
                         select new SelectListItem { Text = c.LocNombre, Value = c.IdLocalidad + "" }).Distinct().ToList();
```

now is working as desired.